# Checkbox group calculate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have several checkbox groups, each group contains 3 checkboxes each (1,X,2).
I want to assign a 100% value to each group (33% to each checkbox in the group). The value will move depending on how many checkboxes are checked. If all 3 are checked then they will have 33% each, but if two are checked they will have 50% each and if only one is checked, then that one will own 100%.
So far I'm only able to elaborate with the lenght of the checkbox and not the value. I'm not that good with Javascript, and therefor I haven't found any good way of doing this. I have a JSFIDDLE with hard coded values:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xc8xt682/2/)

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1_1" class="checkbox" checked id="11" value="on" >
  <label for="11">1</label>
  <span id="Result"></span>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1_X" class="checkbox"checked id="1X" value="on">
  <label for="1X">X</label>
  <span>33%</span>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="1_2" class="checkbox" checked id="12" value="on">
  <label for="12">2</label>
  <span>33%</span>
</td>

window.onload = function () {
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');

  function check() {
    var p = input.checked ? "100" : "0";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = p+'%';
  }
input.onchange = check;
check();
}
```

Comment: Im Sorry, it wasn't my latest JSFIDDLE, I have added my Javascript code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fix your problem i use Jquery and add handler to checkbox and count count input checked.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    var arrayId=$(this).attr("name").split("_");
    var numberId=arrayId[0];
    var percentage=Math.floor(100/$("input[name*='"+numberId+"_']:checked").length);
    console.log(percentage);
    $("input[name*='"+numberId+"_']").parent().children("span").html("0%");
    $("input[name*='"+numberId+"_']:checked").parent().children("span").html(percentage+"%");
});
```

Link JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/xc8xt682/3/

Comment: Thank you @LTasty ! Works like a charm :)

Comment: avoid using attribute selector , its one of the slowest in execution. i can see there is a `class` selector for all the `checkbox`, which is much more faster than `attribute`. *my suggestion:use attribute and pseudo class selector as the last option to traverse the dom*. ref:http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Answer (score 2):

And without jquery, it's just a little bit more verbose. :) LTastys answer's probably better, but just adding mine since I was writing it while he answered.

```
var cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('td')),
    calculate = function () {
        var value = ['100%', '50%', '33%'][cells.filter(function (cell) {
                return cell.querySelector('input').checked;
            }).length - 1];
        cells.forEach(function (cell) {
            var span =  cell.querySelector('span');
            if (cell.querySelector('input').checked) span.textContent = value;
            else span.textContent = '0%';
        });
    };
cells.forEach(function (cell) {
    cell.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', calculate);
});
```